# LAN connectivity issues in Windows

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

We're trying to get a computer and a laptop to connect to each other through LAN.

- Both devices are running the latest version of Windows 11.
- Both devices are on the same network.
- We're both attempting to ping the IP addresses shown when we run ipconfig.

Yet, while the PC pings the laptop successfully, the connection times out when the laptop tries to ping the PC.

We've tried various things like disabling the firewall or using LAN cables in different configurations. None of them get the connectivity to work.

Comment: Have you tried specifically enabling the "Allow ICMP" rules in the firewall?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yeah, it pings correctly now. Thanks!